# How to make a spinner with icons in a form of table layout dynamically?

Tags: android

Anyone know how can i achieve a list like this in the picture? I want to add the images in the project, and create a layout that will pick them up and put them automatically in the layout. Not manually to import all images in the layout. 
So like this if i add a new image in the app then it will be picked automatically.

I didnt try anything yet as am not sure how to do it.

All i found in the web is layouts with each row having 1 icon, but thats not what i want.

Any info or a link i can use anyone?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't do that with a Spinner.
You need to use a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).

Comment: I edit my question. Since you told me i cant do it with spinner i changed the title. Do you know any links or anything that could help me achieve it with gridview?

Comment: I included a link to the Android documentation of the GridView, there is some code for a gridview with an adapter that has images, so what's the problem ? Do you know how to make the popup style ?

Comment: oh i didnt see it was a link. Ill give it a look m8. Yes i know how to do the popupstyle. Hope it will help me solve this, cheers

Comment: I added a comment of my own. I manage to solve it with this post http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com/2010/12/custom-gridview-in-dialog.html

Answer (score 1):

Normally we won't use TableLayout if there are so many images, which will cause Out of Memory Error if too many images loaded. Use GridView instead, very easy and meet your requirements. Look into ApiDemos for some sample codes.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this. Here is the link that helped me out: http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com/2010/12/custom-gridview-in-dialog.html